# Teradata SQL - Using 'OR' returning more records than expecting

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, teradata

the following two queries return around ten records separately.

```
SELECT ACC_NO
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ACC_NO IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
AND DATE = 300618 

SELECT ACC_NO
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ACC_NO IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
AND DATE = 310718
```

However, when I run the two queries combined together

```
SELECT ACC_NO
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ACC_NO IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
AND DATE = 300618 
OR DATE = 310718
```

It returns hundreds of thousands of records. How can this be?

Comment: You need parentheses around the conditions.

Comment: Assuming commonsense precedence rules, your query is same as `(ACC_NO IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND DATE = 300618) OR (DATE = 310718)`

Answer (score 1):

Use IN

```
SELECT ACC_NO
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ACC_NO IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
AND DATE in ( 300618, 310718)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parenthesis if you are using `OR` with `AND` :

```
SELECT ACC_NO
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ACC_NO IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND (DATE = 300618 OR DATE = 310718);
```

However, this is strange if you have more dates, so use `IN` clause instead of huge `OR`s :

```
SELECT ACC_NO
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ACC_NO IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND DATE IN (300618, 310718);
```